# How to export to pdf a multiple selection in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I built a macro that exports parts of worksheets to pdf files. This is working fine except for one table.

Indeed I only need to take the first row and the last 3 rows of the table. The export goes fine but print out each selected part on a different pdf page. I would like it to be on the same page. *(If I manually hide the rows I don't want in the table, select the range and print using Ctrl- P it works.)*

Here is the code I have :

```
'Parcours la plage Accueil contenant les onglets et zones
LastRow = Range("C23").End(xlDown).Row
'Lance l'export pour chaque ligne de la plage
For i = 24 To LastRow
    SheetName = Cells(i, 3)
    PrintArea = Cells(i, 4)
    Name = Cells(i, 2)
    If Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
        Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(Cells(i, 6).Value).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    With Worksheets(SheetName)
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        .Range(ColToHide).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .Range(PrintArea).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "" & chemin & "\" & Name & "_" & an & "-" & mois & ".pdf" _
            , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        .Range(ColToHide).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
Next i
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was thinking in a weird way.

On my manual test I was selecting the whole table but hiding the rows I don't want and then printing. The macro was hiding the rows and still selecting 2 different ranges in one.

All I had to do was change the target range (printarea) in the 'ACCUEIL' sheet. Instead of `A18:Y20,A25:Y28`, I put `A18:Y28` and it worked.